# System.Threading.Timer is not always called

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I wrote a simple helper class for executing delay tasks:

```
public class TaskExecutor {
    private static void Callback(object state) {
        ((Action)state)(); //Not always be called
    }
    public static void DelayExecute(int mSec, Action task) {
        if (task != null) {
            new Timer(Callback, task, mSec, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
TaskExecutor.DelayExecute(10000, () => { Console.WriteLine("Haha..."); });
```

However, the timer does not seem to work everytime. That means sometimes it is fine and sometimes it is bad. Why? And how can I make it right?

Comment: Can you not just use `Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(...);` rather than writing new code and using timers, etc?

Comment: Also, your specific problem is addressed in the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx): "As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes, I think that's the problem. I didn't keep a reference to the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have somewhere a reference to `Timer` object you created. Otherwise it will be collected by GC.